# How can I make Contact form 7 return the checkbox label and not the value data on mailing a form?

Tags: php, forms, contact-form-7

I have a Contact form 7 that the client insists goes to different mailboxes based on checkbox selection.

I can do this by:

```
[checkbox* your-recipient class:checks label_first use_label_element exclusive "Sales | email@address1.co.uk" "Rent| email@address2.co.uk"]
```

This works perfectly but on the mail form they want the subject to be the key and not the value?

```
Subject: Contact form enquiry - [your-recipient]
```

This returns either:

```
 Subject: Contact form enquiry - email@address1.co.uk
 Subject: Contact form enquiry - email@address2.co.uk
```

Is there a way to make the subject read:

```
 Subject: Contact form enquiry - Sales
 Subject: Contact form enquiry - Rent
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get value before pipe, you use [*raw*{field name}] in your case :

```
Subject: Contact form enquiry - [_raw_your-recipient]
```

Answer (score 2):

*I learn best from example, so that's how I'm showing how we do this. I use a pipe to redirect and *raw* to display the office/title of the email*

**In Your form tab:**

```
destination-email
     "Checkbox Title|email_for_this_choice@whatever.org"
```

**In your mail tab**

```
TO: [destination-email]
```

**And in the mail tab, message body, if desired:**

```
<dl>
  <dt>Checkbox Group Title(s) - 
  Email Name - email address</dt><dd><b>[_raw_destination-email] - [destination-email]</b></dd>
</dl>
```